# Is it "the position of particles" or "the positions of particles"?

Tags: grammatical-number

Having many objects (particles) with one property (position), what is grammatically correct?

- the particles' position
- the particles' positions

It should be noted, that it is possible for one particle to have many positions (over time). And it is also possible for many particles to have one position (if they are considered to be clustered).

But I want to express the case, where many particles are distributed wildly across space at a specific point in time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case it should be *particles' positions*, unless all the particles had one position, which is not the case. Here is an example:

> "To specify the state of the system is to list all the particles' positions and momenta because Newton's equations..."

That said, you can drop the possessive apostrophe altogether and use *particle positions* or *particle position*, where *particle* acts as a modifier.

Comment: ... excellent answer, but I would add that the more precisely the position of individual particles is known, the less correct - in a context like that - is the singular form 'particle', and vice versa! +1, anyway ...